# Vertical and horizontal lines in the returned results table are disjointed

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning

I have a problem "Recognizing student transcripts" from a photo, and I followed the instructions of this article: [https://kananvyas.medium.com/a-box-detection-algorithm-for-any- image-containing-boxes-756c15d7ed26](https://kananvyas.medium.com/a-box-detection-algorithm-for-any-%20image-containing-boxes-756c15d7ed26)

Everything is fine, vertical and horizontal lines are recognizable, but they are not seamless. I was planning to turn the 0s up to 255, but in the case of the image below, I don't know what to do, because the vertical and horizontal lines are not straight lines (pic 1):
[pic 1 and pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh2G2.png)

How do I get pic 2 from pic 1?

Comment: See cv2.HoughLines()

Answer (score 0):

@fmw42 is correct with his comment.
You will have to do that in multiple steps.

1. Apply pre-processing to remove noise if those data are scanned (that helps after).
2. Apply Hough lines algorithm and get all the lines that are detected, you store them in an array.
3. You check all those lines and you measure their angles. You want vertical and horizontal lines right ? Then you get the angle, you put some kind of threshold, for example 0 degree +/- 10 degrees ? 90 degrees +/- 10 degrees (this will remove the lines found by the Hough algorithm but which are actually found on noisy data).
4. You go through that array and you filter all the lines that do not comply with your angle threshold setting.

Now you have some results that you will still need to process.

5. You merge all the lines that are closed to each other and sharing the same type of angle within another range. This will give you another array of lines.
6. You use this new array. This gives you Pic2.